# Bootstrap 4 modal events not firing

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-carousel

I have web page on which I have a carousel of images and instead of embedding the youtube video into the carousel I've put an image with a youtube icon and on its click the modal open with the youtube video.

Since the carousel is fed the images and youtube link dynamically, I've put the youtube link in the div which fires the modal.

The issue is that the modal opens but the 'show.bs.modal' or 'hide.bs.modal' events don't work, hence the never gets the youtube video link.

**HTML**

```
<!--Carousel-->

<div id="carouselIndicatorsDiv" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators filterInvert1">

    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselIndicatorsDiv" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon filterInvert1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselIndicatorsDiv" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon filterInvert1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>

<!--Modal-->

<div class="modal fade" id="ytSubsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ytSubsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="ytSubsVideo"  allowscriptaccess="always" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
//Appended other images, appending image for modal click

$(".carousel-inner").append('<div id="ytSrcLink" class="carousel-item cursorPointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ytSubsModal" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HHncD0yt71c?autoplay=1"><img class="d-block position-relative w-100" src="img/1/thumbnail.jpg"><img src="img/youtubeIcon.svg" class="position-absolute center youtubeIconStyle"></div>');

// Modal

var videoYtSubsSource;

$("#ytSrcLink").on('click', function(){
    videoYtSubsSource = $(this).attr('src');
    assignYtSubsSrc(videoYtSubsSource);
});

// Youtube Modal
var ytSubsSrc;

function assignYtSubsSrc(videoUrl){
    ytSubsSrc=videoUrl;
}

$(document).on('show.bs.modal', "#ytSubsModal", function(e) {
    $('#ytSubsVideo').attr('src',ytSubsSrc); 
});

$(document).on('hide.bs.modal', "#ytSubsModal", function(e) {
    $('#ytSubsVideo').attr('src','');
});
```

I even tried by just directly putting the modal triggering div in HTML and then try, but that also didn't work.
I think I'm missing something basic, but not sure what.

Comment: if you include a a minimal working example which recreates the issue, it'll be easier to help

Comment: @AkberIqbal Thank you for making me code a working example, it made me explore what I was doing wrong, as independently the code was working. Can you please see the answer I posted and guide me further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work, apparently the issue was that I included the whole jquery code mentioned in the question under $(document).ready(function() {});

Whereas the Bootstrap's events for show and hide had to be put outside document.ready function.

But I'm still not sure why it is so, can anyone guide?

Comment: anything inside `$(document).ready` would be triggered once DOM has loaded completely... so in your case, if `carousel-inner` is not loaded, you wouldn't be able to append anything to it; coming to your point about Bootstrap's show/hide... you're using the default functions, right? they would be part of `bootstrap.js` and would be inside a `$(document).ready` also...

Comment: @AkberIqbal oh that makes sense. Thank you! :)